# Number of solutions of a Diophantine equation

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm currently studying about the solutions of the $x_1\pm x_2\pm\cdots\pm x_m=0$, where the $x_i$'s are positive integers. They started with a trigonometric identity
\begin{equation}
\cos(x_1) \cos(x_2)\cdots\cos(x_m)=\dfrac{1}{2^{m-1}}\sum \cos(x_1\pm x_2\pm\cdots\pm x_m)
\end{equation}
where the sum is taken over all possible choices of signs $+$ and $-$. Later, they arrived to the conclusion that the number of solutions of the equation $x_1\pm x_2\pm\cdots\pm x_m=0$ (all the possible choices of signs) is given by the integral
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{2^{m-1}}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x_1t) \cos(x_2t)\cdots\cos(x_mt)dt
\end{equation}
which of course can be simplified further (by using the fact that the integrant is an even function) as
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{2^{m-1}}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x_1t) \cos(x_2t)\cdots\cos(x_mt)dt
\end{equation}
How they did arrived to that integral representation? I can't figure out this. Any help given will be appreciated.

Comment: I already edited the question. It refers to the number of choices of signs of the given equation

Comment: Where can I get the proof of the above trigonometric identity ?

Comment: I have tried to found a link for you that provides a proof of the identity, but I didn't have any success. But from what I can see, I think it can be proved using induction in the number of angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $t$, you have the given trigonometric identity
$$\cos(x_1t) \cos(x_2t)\cdots\cos(x_mt)=\dfrac{1}{2^{m-1}}\sum \cos(x_1t\pm x_2t\pm\cdots\pm x_mt)$$

where, as you said, the sum is taken over all possible choices of signs $+$ and $−$.

Now integrate this between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ : you get
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x_1t) \cos(x_2t)\cdots\cos(x_mt) dt=\dfrac{1}{2^{m-1}}\sum \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos((x_1\pm x_2\pm\cdots\pm x_m)t) dt$$

But the integral $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos((x_1\pm x_2\pm\cdots\pm x_m)t) dt$$
is equal to $2\pi$ if $x_1\pm x_2\pm\cdots\pm x_m = 0$, and is equal to $0$ otherwise (because the $x_i$'s are integers). So if $N$ denotes the number of solutions of the equation, you get directly that
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x_1t) \cos(x_2t)\cdots\cos(x_mt) dt=\dfrac{1}{2^{m-1}} 2\pi N$$

so
$$N = \frac{2^{m-1}}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x_1t) \cos(x_2t)\cdots\cos(x_mt) dt$$

which is the given integral representation.

Comment: Excellent answer!!! Thank you very much! Now it is clear why they arrived to that integral. I really appreciated your help!

Comment: @user463019 You are welcome !

Comment: I have one last question: isn't better to just obtain the number $N$ directly from the above identity for cosines? That is, if we evaluate the sum in the RHS of the identity, when $(x_1\pm\cdots\pm x_n)t=0$, then $\dfrac{1}{2^{m-1}}\sum \cos((x_1\pm\cdots\pm x_n)t)=\dfrac{1}{2^{m-1}}N$. Then solving for $N$, we get $N=2^{m-1}\prod_i \cos(x_i t)$. It is correct what I have done?

Comment: @user463019 No, the problem is that $\cos((x_1 \pm ... \pm x_n)t)$ *is not* equal to $0$ when $x_1 \pm ... \pm x_n$ is not a solution of the equation. So in the sum, you cannot forget the terms that correspond to the non-solutions of the equation. Whereas when you integrate, these terms precisely vanish.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks a lot again!